# Unblockable method in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, refactoring, spring-webflux

IntelliJ is saying: inappropriate blocking method call

How can I refactor this method to pass this standard?

```
public List<User> getAllUsers(String name) {
        Type userList = new TypeToken<List<User>>() {
        }.getType();

        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity
                    = restTemplate.getForEntity(host, String.class);
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();


            List<User> users = gson.fromJson(responseEntity.getBody(), userList );

            return users == null ? new ArrayList<>() : users;

        } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: On which line..?

Comment: AndyTurner I edited. Michael When i invoke this method in rest controller

Comment: Additionally, you don't use `name`.

Comment: Yeah, I am not using it at this moment - I will add filter, now  I am getting all data from some api, but I was wonder why is IntelliJ telling me about blocking..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ is warning you because you're using WebFlux which is non-blocking, but also `RestTemplate` which is blocking. You should switch to [WebClient](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-resttemplate) instead, which is the new non-blocking way.

Comment: Thanks! :) this is the answer i was looking for :)